# In version 10 EvaluationCompletionAction "ShowTiming" no longer gives useful output; any solutions?

Tags: front-end, bugs, options, timing

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0, fixed in 10.0.2**

---

In version 10 using this Front End option no longer gives useful output:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, EvaluationCompletionAction->"ShowTiming"]
```

In version 7 the time to evaluate and render would be printed in the window frame (status area) of the Notebook.  In version 10 even a long evaluation prints a small value.  I can *briefly* see a larger number flash before it is overwritten by a small value.

1. Why is the useful timing being overwritten by an apparently meaningless one?
2. Is there a way to restore the old timing behavior?  I am quite attached to this functionality.

---

As an example, evaluating this I can see a momentary flash of "Time: 3.xx seconds" before it is replaced with e.g. "Time: 0.06 seconds":

```
Plot[{BesselJ[1, x], BesselJ[2, x]}, {x, 0, 10},
 PlotPoints -> 1*^5, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}}
]
```

Comment: I was told weeks ago that this was reported

Comment: @Rojo So it is a confirmed bug?  I'll mark it as such.  Was any solution provided?

Comment: No solutions provided but I got the impression that it will be fixed soon

Comment: @Rojo This bug fix did not make it into 10.0.1.

Comment: Oh, thanks of the c%#ppy heads up. I still don't have 10.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed in 10.0.2. The longer time now remain in the status windows. On windows 7, 64 bit

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, EvaluationCompletionAction -> "ShowTiming"]
Plot[{BesselJ[1, x], BesselJ[2, x]}, {x, 0, 10}, PlotPoints -> 1*^5, 
    Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]